# In SQL, How to get Count, Group by based on Like Message on a specific column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below query will execute a Table of records with Error, Error Types and its count.

I have to group by further based on Like messages in the  ErrorType Column.

So I created another Table which has all Like Error Type Messages.

I have to write some kind of join between my Actual table and Like Error Messages Table to get the result. How should i do that ?

```
create table #t
(Stepname varchar(100),
TotalStepError int,
StepExec nvarchar(1000),
ErrorTypeCount int
)

insert into #t values
('Payment',1,'calculationError',1),
('POS', 2,  'Deadlock Error on 07/21/2016', 1),
('POS', 2,  'Deadlock Error on 07/22/2016', 1),
('verification',    6,  'Timeout Error',    1),
('verification',    6,  'Webservice call error',    1),
('verification',    6,  'Webservice call error on 07/23/2016',  1),
('verification',    6,  'Webservice call error on 07/24/2016',  1),
('verification',    6,  'Webservice Response',  2)


select * from #t



-- This is based on Like Type 

Create Table #ErrorLikeType
(
    TypeLike varchar(1000)
)

Insert into #ErrorLikeType values
('Webservice call error'),
('Timeout error')

select * from #ErrorLikeType

--Expected Result  - I have to write some kind of relation between my Temp Table and Like type table.

Stepname        TotalStepError  StepExec                        ErrorTypeCount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Payment             1           calculationError                    1
POS                 2           Deadlock Error                      2
verification        6           Timeout Error                       1
verification        6           Webservice call error               3
verification        6           Webservice Response                 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be using sub-selects (although you can find more elegant solutions using cross-apply):

```
select *
from (
    select StepName,
           count(*) as TotalStepError
    from #t
    where StepExecResult = "Error"
    group by StepName
    ) as t1
inner join (
    select StepName,
           StepExec,
           count(*) as ErrorTypeCount
    from #t
    where StepExecResult = "Error"
    group by StepName,
          StepExec
    ) as t2
on  t2.StepName = t1.StepName
```

Also, why was the original post down-voted? The OP has code with an attempt to solve it...